# store generated data in list and add header using python

Tags: python, python-2.7

This code download data in terms of table structure and i tried putting that table in list so that i can further use it to store in database , i have tried to append another empty row in this for header since it gives first entity as its header. 
Problem is it gives square brackets on extreme left not even replacing the default header and i don't know how to put this table in list to add further in database.

Code:

```
import urllib
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd

urls = ["http://physics.iitd.ac.in/content/list-faculty-members"]
i = 0

while i< len(urls):
    htmlfile = urllib.urlopen(urls[i])
    htmltext = htmlfile.read()
    soup = bs(htmltext, "lxml")
    tables  = pd.read_html(urls[i])
    dataframe = tables[0]

    x = [[]]

    for dataframes in tables:
        x.append(dataframe)

    print x
    i+=1
```

Comment: Just at first glance, the first item of `x` will always be an empty list, because that's what you start with and you're just appending to it. You probably want to change it to `x = []`

Comment: i tried 'x= []' its adding starting bracket to very start of the output and ending bracket to very end. @C_Z_